# Maven repository behind captcha

Tags: maven, artifactory, captcha

I need to access maven repository(artifactory), protected with captcha. If i try to open it with a browser i need to solve the captcha, and then i can browse it. The problem is when i need to use maven to download artifacts, because maven can't solve captcha. Is there some kind of proxy, that i can install locally, and every time captcha is asked, i will solve it manually, and proxy will save cookies, and send it together with a request, that i don't need to solve captcha every time, and that maven can access that repository. Or is there some other solution for this problem.

Comment: That sounds rather odd. What is the value of setting up a Maven repo, which is normally intended to be accessed by an automated script, behind a captcha to prevent it from being accessed by an automated script.

Comment: Artifactory has an API.  You (or the repository owner) should be able to create the appropriate credentials needed.

Comment: The repository is accessible from internet, and the servers that are in front of the repository identifies my IP as suspicious. I can't change it.

Comment: Talk to the team which looks after that repository.